# parsimonious parser - error trying to parse assignment grammar

Tags: python, parsing, peg, parsimonious

I'm using the [Python Parsimonious Parser](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious) to try to build an interpreter for a simple language I'm designing. I watched this [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1h1mM7VwNGo) which was very helpful, and now I'm slowly modifying the code to match my own rules. I'm stuck on an assignment rule originally defined as:

```
def assignment(self, node, children):
    'assignment = lvalue "=" expr'
    lvalue, _, expr = children
    self.env[lvalue] = expr
    return expr
```

I modified the rule slightly with the following grammar:

```
def assignment(self, node, children):
    'assignment = "SET" lvalue "," expr'
    _, lvalue, _, expr = children
    self.env[lvalue] = expr
    return expr
```

I'd like the parser to evaluate `SET a, 7` for example, the same as `a = 7` and bind the value `7` to the name `a`. However, when I attempt to parse it, I get this error from the Parsimonious library:

```
parsimonious.exceptions.IncompleteParseError: Rule 'program' matched in its 
entirety, but it didn't consume all the text. The non-matching portion of 
the text begins with 'SET a, 7' (line 1, column 1).
```

I'm fairly new to parsing/lexing and am not entirely sure if I defined the rule correctly. Was hoping someone with more parsing/lexing experience can help me properly define the rule and explain where I went wrong. Also perhaps explain the Parsimonious error to me?

Comment: Unfortunately, the video seems unavailable now. Is there an alternative link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was trying to parse `SET a, 7`, my `lvalue` rule did not take into account the whitespace between the `SET` and the lvalue `a`. This is because I defined my `lvalue` rule as `'lvalue = ~"[A-Za-z]+" _'` which doesn't take into account whitespace before the name. I redefined my assignment rule as follows to account for whitespace between the `GET` and the name:

```
'setvar = "SETVAR" _ lvalue _ "," _ expr'
```

Parsimonious seems to like that a lot better.

Comment: Note: the _ is another rule defined as `'_ = ~"\s*"' (i.e. indefinite whitespace).