# Why is Parsimonious rejecting my input with an IncompleteParseError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, peg, parsimonious

I've been trying to work out the basic skeleton for a language I've been designing, and I'm *attempting* to use [Parsimonious](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious) to do the parsing for me. As of right now, I've, declared the following grammar:

```
grammar = Grammar(
    """
    program = expr*
    expr    = _ "{" lvalue (rvalue / expr)* "}" _
    lvalue  = _ ~"[a-z0-9\\-]+" _
    rvalue  = _ ~".+" _
    _       = ~"[\\n\\s]*"
    """
)
```

When I try to output the resulting AST of a simple input string like `"{ do-something some-argument }"`:

> ```
> print(grammar.parse("{ do-something some-argument }"))
> ```

Parsimonious decides to flat-out reject it, and then gives me this somewhat cryptic error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "tests.py", line 13, in <module>
>     print(grammar.parse("{ do-something some-argument }"))
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parsimonious/grammar.py", line 112, in parse
>     return self.default_rule.parse(text, pos=pos)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parsimonious/expressions.py", line 109, in parse
>     raise IncompleteParseError(text, node.end, self)
> parsimonious.exceptions.IncompleteParseError: Rule 'program' matched in its entirety, but it didn't consume all the text. The non-matching portion of the text begins with '{ do-something some-' (line 1, column 1).
> ```

At first I thought this might be an issue related to my whitespace rule, `_`, but after a few failed attempts at removing the whitespace rule in certain places, I was still coming up with the same error.

I've tried searching online, but all I've found that seems to be remotely related, is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966779/parsimonious-parser-error-trying-to-parse-assignment-grammar), which didn't help me in any way.

Am I doing something wrong with my grammar? Am I not parsing the input in the correct way? If anyone has a possible solution to this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `rvalue  = _ ~"[a-z\\-]+" _` works, with nothing else changed. I do not know Parsimonious at all well, but I'm reasonably familiar with regexes and used to be with yacc; my hypothesis is that `.+` is greedily matching the rest of the input string, leaving nothing to match the rest of the production.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yup. Changing the `.+` to something else helped. If you want to post an answer about it, feel free to :-).

Comment: Massively revised answer. I Get It now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am very far from an expert on Parsimonious, but I believe the problem is that `~".+"` is greedily matching the whole remainder of the input string, leaving nothing to match the rest of the production. I initially tested that idea by changing the regex for `rvalue` to `~"[a-z0-9\\-]+"`, same as the one you have for `lvalue`. Now it parses, and (awesomely) distinguishes by context between the two identically defined tokens `lvalue` and `rvalue`.

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar

grammar = Grammar(
    """
    program = expr*
    expr    = _ "{" lvalue (rvalue / expr)* "}" _
    lvalue  = _ ~"[a-z0-9\\-]+" _
    rvalue  = _ ~"[a-z0-9\\-]+" _
    _       = ~"[\\n\\s]*"
    """
)

print(grammar.parse( "{ do-something some-argument }"))
```

If you mean for `rvalue` to match any sequence of non-whitespace characters, you want something more like this:

```
rvalue = _ ~"[^\\s\\n]+" _
```

But whoops!

```
{ foo bar }
```

`"}"` is a closing curly brace, but it's also a sequence of one or more non-whitespace characters. Is it `"}"` or `rvalue`? The grammar says the next token can be either of those. One of those interpretations is parsable and the other isn't, but Parsimonious just says it's spinach and the hell with it. I don't know if a parsing maven would consider that a legitimate way to resolve the ambiguity (e.g. maybe such a grammar may result in cases with two possible interpretations that *both* parse), or how practical that would be to implement. In any case Parsimonious doesn't make that call.

So we need to repel boarders on the curly brace issue. I think this grammar does what you want:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar

grammar = Grammar(
    """
    program = expr*
    expr    = _ "{" lvalue (expr / rvalue)* "}" _
    lvalue  = _ ~"[a-z0-9\\-]+" _
    rvalue  = _ ~"[^{}\\n\\s]+" _
    _       = ~"[\\n\\s]*"
    """
)

print(grammar.match( "{ do-something some-argument 23423 {foo bar} &^%$ }"))
```

I excluded open curly brace as well, because how would you expect this string to tokenize?

```
{foo bar{baz poo}}
```

I would expect

```
"{" "foo" "bar" "{" "baz" "poo" "}" "}"
```

...because if `"poo}"` is expected to tokenize as `"poo"` `"}"`, and `"{foo"` is expected to tokenize as `"{"` `"foo"`, then treating `bar{baz` as `"bar{baz"` or `"bar{"` `"baz"` is <strike>deranged</strike>counterintuitive.

Now I remember how my bitter hatred of yacc drove me to an obsession with it.

Comment: About your comment whether Parsimonious could resolve the ambiguity; _PEGs_, which is what Parsimonious implements, are unambiguous by definition. If your grammar reads `a / b`, it means "if `a` matches, parse it as an `a` and only if `a` does not match but `b` matches, parse it as a `b`". Alternatives are asymmetric.